# Google Maps API, смена центра карты

Tags: javascript, html5, google-maps-api, google-maps

На сайте на диапазоне ниже **992px** нужно изменить центр google карты.

Пробовал внутрь функции карты написать уловия **if($(window).innerWidth() < 993)**, но тогда при первом открытии **index.html** карта совсем не загружается, и в консоли показывает ошибку на строке, где находится условия, а если обновить страницу, то тогда все становится на место, карта появляется, центр ее меняется на диапазоне ниже 992px и ошибки нет.

В чем может быть проблема, как правильно решить вопрос смены центра карты. Саму карту подключал через внешний файл **google-maps.js**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код, который в google-maps.js**

```
function initMap() {

var centerLatLng = {lat: 46.485831, lng: 30.662000};

if($(window).innerWidth() < 993) {
    var centerLatLng = {lat: 46.484050, lng: 30.659420};
};

var element = document.getElementById('google-map');
var options = {
    zoom: 17,
    center: centerLatLng,
    scrollwheel: false,
};

var myMap = new google.maps.Map(element, options);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 46.485550, lng: 30.659420},
    map: myMap,
    icon: 'images/base/google-marker.png'
});

marker.addListener('click', function () {
    InfoWindow.open(myMap, marker);
});
};
```

**Ошибка в консоли при первом запуске index.html**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Замените `$(window).innerWidth()` например на `window.innerWidth`

Comment: @tutankhamun, спасибо, действительно помогло! а в чем разница  между window.innerWidth и $(window).innerWidth(), в каких случаях какой вариант использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerWidth()` - метод *jQuery*. Доступен только после загрузки jQuery. Видимо в момент инициализации карты *jQuery* еще не загружен. Кроме того, судя по [документации](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/), этот метод вообще не подходит для `$(window)`.

> This method is not applicable to window and document objects; for these, use .width() instead.

В вашем случае достаточно заменить `$(window).innerWidth()` на `window.innerWidth`.

`window.innerWidth` - глобальное свойство. В браузере доступно для скриптов всегда

Если обязательно нужны *jQuery* методы, придется сделать отложенную инициализацию